# Django Rest Framework Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework, i'm trying to get some field from my models

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        ordering = ['score' , 'username']
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'user' ,'first_name', 'last_name', 'reg_number' ,'score', 'classroom')
```

my problem is that i get just : 
-id
-username
-first_name
-last_name
-score

but i can't get the reg_number and classroom
even if i delete all fields :

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        ordering = ['score' , 'username']
```

i get the some result.

I have this problem just with 3 models : User & Student & Professor ( Student and Professor are inhereted from User )

my student model :

```
class Student(User):
    reg_number = models.IntegerField()
    classroom = models.ForeignKey(Classroom)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    skills = models.TextField(blank=True)
    interest = models.TextField(blank=True)
    about = models.TextField(blank=True)
    projects = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Comment: Your serialiser definitions look fine. I just tested an equivalent Model inheritance graph with DRF v3.1.1. Potentially it's an issue with the Model defintions. Can you share those too?

Comment: i just changed the names adding "s" to Student"s" ..... in my view and serialiser and everything works . but i cant get the problem ^^

Comment: It's not clear what "names" you're changing.... Model class names, Field attribute names, literal strings representing the model/field names. So it's hard to help you understand where the problem was. Glad you got it working anyway.

Comment: Serializer.py : 
class UserSerializer ==> class UsersSerialize
....
views.py:
class User"s"List(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
....

Answer (score 0):

Can you include your student model definition.?? The reason may be ur student model contains reverse relationship in any other models. You have explicitly include that field in serializer. Checkout reverse relations topic in following link
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#reverse-relations

Comment: i joined the student model ;)